# Impedir copia de texto no site, e no lugar mostrar outro texto

Tags: javascript

Opa, estou criando um site, e desejo impedir que alguém copie qualquer palavra dele. Alias quero permitir a seleção e a copia, porem junto com o texto copiado, quando a pessoa colar, vim mais um texto pré definido por mim com um link.

Ex.: "Está copia é indevida, veja o original em: www.original.com."

Ainda não tenho nada de código, se puderem me ajudar eu agradeço.

Comment: tente tratar o evento "oncopy" mas isso nunca vai impedir o usuário de visualizar o código fonte e copiar

Comment: Qualquer pessoa com um pouco de conhecimento conseguirá burlar isso.

Comment: Marcaram como duplicata de uma pergunta que é o contrário po. Desmarca isso aí!

Comment: Como assim o contrário @LeAndrade? A resposta no link mostra como copiar qualquer coisa para o clipboard, não é isso que a pergunta precisa no fundo?

Comment: @bfavaretto Ao meu ver não. Uma quer copiar para área de transferência e esta quer impedir a copia e executar outra ação no lugar.

Comment: "Alias quero permitir a seleção e a copia, porem junto com o texto copiado, quando a pessoa colar, vim mais um texto pré definido por mim com um link."  @LeAndrade

Comment: É que no título ele quer impedir, no corpo da pergunta ele quer deixar. Ta bom tbm vai, o cara que fez a pergunta tbm não vem editar a pergunta e explicar o que ele realmente. Pode marcar mesmo mesmo man :) @bfavaretto